# How to end current session manually when the user exits the tab?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I am using the new gtag Google Analytics script
I would like to end the active session when the user exits the page using the window.onunload event.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a documented way to force re-start of a GA session using **gtag.js**.

However, if you use analytics.js or GTM, you can use the [session control field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sessionControl).