# using google analytics but can't make user and session data to work. how can I fix it?

Tags: google-analytics

[image: screenshot]

I'm new to GA and am using gtag with angular. I tried analytics.js but the {sessionControl:start} wasn't working either. my tracking id is UA-158347009-1  and its what im using on my gtag configs. I can make event hits and pageview hits just fine, just the session and user stuff isn't working. Any clue on what I might be missing?

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-158347009-1"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-158347009-1')

  </script>
```

Comment: Hi @rebecca, welcome to StackOverflow. It will be great if you can add more details to your question. The less a member have to ask followup questions on your post faster you will get your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that [GA data processing latency is 24-48 hours](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) and because of that, the graph on the left ends on the previous day (while the one on the right shows you only the last 30 minutes).

Regarding the [session control field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sessionControl) - it's available only for `analytics.js` and what you're using is `gtag.js` (this part of your question is a duplicate of [How to end current session manually when the user exits the tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554613/how-to-end-current-session-manually-when-the-user-exits-the-tab))